# Creating a HTTPS Server in Java - Where is the local Certificates?

Tags: java, ssl

i found some tutorial to handle with https server and a https client. i created some keystore and it works fine. But i have some question which is not clear from the tutorial.

this is my https-server

```
public class HTTPSServer {

    private int port = 9999;
    private boolean isServerDone = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HTTPSServer server = new HTTPSServer();
        server.run();
    }

    HTTPSServer() {
    }

    HTTPSServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    // Create the and initialize the SSLContext
    private SSLContext createSSLContext() {
        try {

            //Returns keystore object in definied type, here jks
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            //loads the keystore from givin input stream, and the password to unclock jks
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("x509-ca.jks"), "password".toCharArray());

            // Create key manager
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

            // Create trust manager
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
            TrustManager[] tm = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

            // opens a secure socket with definied protocol
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

            //System.out.println(keyStore.getCertificate("root").getPublicKey());
            //System.out.println(keyStore.isKeyEntry("root"));
            sslContext.init(km, tm, null);

            return sslContext;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Start to run the server
    public void run() {
        SSLContext sslContext = this.createSSLContext();

        try {
            // Create server socket factory
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();

            // Create server socket
            SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(this.port);

            System.out.println("SSL server started");
            while (!isServerDone) {
                SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();

                // Start the server thread
                new ServerThread(sslSocket).start();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Thread handling the socket from client
    static class ServerThread extends Thread {

        private SSLSocket sslSocket = null;

        ServerThread(SSLSocket sslSocket) {
            this.sslSocket = sslSocket;
        }

        public void run() {
            sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            //System.out.println("HIER: " + sslSocket.getHandshakeSession());

            //Klappt nicht, auch nicht, wenn der Client diese Zeile ebenfalls besitzt
            //sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"});
            try {
                // Start handshake
                sslSocket.startHandshake();

                // Get session after the connection is established
                SSLSession sslSession = sslSocket.getSession();
                System.out.println(sslSession.getPeerHost());
                System.out.println(sslSession.getLocalCertificates());
                System.out.println("\tProtocol : " + sslSession.getProtocol());
                System.out.println("\tCipher suite : " + sslSession.getCipherSuite());
                System.out.println("\tSession context : " + sslSession.getSessionContext());
                //System.out.println("\tPeer pricipal of peer : " + sslSession.getPeerPrincipal());

                // Start handling application content
                InputStream inputStream = sslSocket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outputStream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

                String line = null;

                String[] suites = sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
                for (int i = 0; i < suites.length; i++) {
                    //System.out.println(suites[i]);
                    //System.out.println(sslSession.getCipherSuite());
                }

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Inut : " + line);

                    if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Write data
                printWriter.print("HTTP/1.1 200\r\n");
                printWriter.flush();

                sslSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
SSL server started
127.0.0.1
null
    Protocol : TLSv1.2
    Cipher suite : TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    Session context : sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl@781df1a4
```

I want to know, why the line

```
 System.out.println(sslSession.getLocalCertificates());
```

prints out "null"?

Thank you a lot, Mira

Comment: Does `x509-ca.jks` contain any private keys? The documentation says "If no certificates were sent, then null is returned.", which indicates you did not send any certificates from the client to the server.

Comment: The client does not send any certificate, because i never set an client authentication. But during the handshake the server is sending a certificate to the client. So i have thought, i would see some certificate with this line. No, in x509-ca.jks there is just a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getLocalCertificates--):

> `Certificate[] getLocalCertificates()`
>
> Returns the certificate(s) that were sent to the peer during handshaking.
>
> Note: This method is useful only when using certificate-based cipher suites.
>
> When multiple certificates are available for use in a handshake, the implementation chooses what it considers the "best" certificate chain available, and transmits that to the other side. This method allows the caller to know which certificate chain was actually used.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> an ordered array of certificates, with the local certificate first followed by any certificate authorities. If no certificates were sent, then `null` is returned.

The part we care about is "Returns the certificate(s) that were sent to the peer during handshaking.", and "This method is useful only when using certificate-based cipher suites.".

Given that it is returning `null`, we can assume you are not sending any certificates to the client. But it's also HTTPS, so what gives? Well, it looks like you're using `TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`, which is, as the name suggests, *anonymous*. As per the [OpenSSL Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman#Diffie-Hellman_in_SSL.2FTLS):

> **Anonymous Diffie-Hellman** uses Diffie-Hellman, but without authentication. Because the keys used in the exchange are not authenticated, the protocol is susceptible to Man-in-the-Middle attacks. Note: if you use this scheme, a call to `SSL_get_peer_certificate` will return `NULL` because you have selected an anonymous protocol. This is the only time `SSL_get_peer_certificate` is allowed to return `NULL` under normal circumstances.

While this is applicable to OpenSSL, it would appear to be the same in Java - that is, you're not using a certificate-based cipher. Someone with more knowledge of TLS would need to jump in, but it looks like AES keys *are* generated, and they're sent to the client, but the client has no assurance those keys came from you, whereas normally you would generate the keys, and then sign / encrypt (not 100% sure) those keys with an RSA key to prove they came from you.

To fix this, I believe you would need to select a different cipher suite, e.g. `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`. I'm not 100% sure *how* you would do this, but that would appear to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
```

You are enabling all the anonymous and low-grade cipher suites, so you are allowing the server not to send a certificate, so it doesn't send one, so it doesn't give you one in `getLocalCertificates()`.

Remove this line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried your possible solution, but i got a SSLHandShakeException: no cipher suites in common. Go ahead.